# Parsing a very simple CSV and printing the first column in F#

Tags: f#, f#-data

I'm trying to write the following C# code to F#:

```
List<string> addresses = File.ReadLines(CsvPath).Select(x => x.Split(';')[0]).Distinct().ToList();
addresses.ForEach(a => Console.WriteLine(a));
```

This is what I've come up with:

```
let addresses = File.ReadLines(CsvPath) |> Seq.iter (fun s1 ->
    s1.Split [|';'|].[0]
    |> Console.WriteLine
)
```

However this outputs System.String[] instead of the first string value of the line...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the argument of `s1.Split` in parentheses, so you actually index on the result, not the argument.

```ml
let addresses = 
    File.ReadLines(CsvPath)
    |> Seq.iter (fun s1 ->
        s1.Split([|';'|]).[0]
        |> Console.WriteLine)
```